# Ruby Object name to string

Tags: ruby, class, object, logging

I have a strange need that I can't find a good solution to.

I've got a method that I will pass either an object, hash, or array to. And I want to be able to get the name of that object, hash, or array that i'm passing.

Here is an example:

```
@user = User.find(5)

log_info(@user)

def log_info(obj)
  Rails.logger.debug(obj.to_s)
  Rails.logger.debug(obj.inspect)
end
```

That would log something like:

```
@user
{"active"=>true, "address1"=>"something", "address2"=>"", "city"=>"somewhere"}
```

This would just prevent me from having to do this:

```
@user = User.find(5)

log_info("@user", @user)

def log_info(heading, obj)
  Rails.logger.debug(heading)
  Rails.logger.debug(obj.inspect)
end
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You want the name of the parameter on the calling side?

Comment: In the context `log_info(@user)`, `@user` is just a reference without any notion of its name. So, no, you can't get the name of `@user` from `log_info(@user)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a little hackery - i'll just leave this here:

```
class Reference
    def initialize(var_name, vars)
      @var_name = var_name
      @getter = eval "lambda { #{var_name} }", vars
    end
    def name 
      @var_name
    end
    def value
      @getter.call
    end
end
def log_info(ref)
  Rails.logger.debug(ref.name.to_s)
  Rails.logger.debug(ref.value.inspect)
end
def ref(&block)
  Reference.new(block.call, block.binding)
end
@user = "something";
log_info(ref{:@user}) # -> @user - "something"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your case only requires to work with instance variables, you could do something like this:

```
def log_info(obj)
  heading = instance_variables.detect {|name| instance_variable_get(name).equal?(obj) }
  Rails.logger.debug(heading)
  Rails.logger.debug(obj.inspect)
end
```